# resource for renderscript computation

Tags: android, renderscript

I am new to android and want to learn renderscript for performing computation instead for rendering graphics, the documentation at developer site is not good can anyone suggest something to start with renderscript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Renderscript while isn't that hard, may be a bit advanced for someone 'new to android'. Describe what you are trying to do and what you have tried, SO works best with specific questions rather than vague 'find for me/teach me' types of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [Larry Schiefer's A Deep Dive into RenderScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ynA92x8WQo) video. This was of great help to me when trying to understand RS given the very limited documentation there exists (and the little info there is always focuses on image filters...)

On his video, he goes through all the basics of the framework to understand how it actually works internally, and shows a demo program on using it for the computation of a Mandelbrot fractal. Best resource to get started with this IMHO.

After watching that, I would also recommend simply browsing through all the [RenderScript tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/renderscript) posted here on StackOverflow, there's lots of useful information that can be found right here too.